# cannot enable saas mode for app in wso2as 5.2.1

Tags: wso2, saas

I'm playing with wso2 AS 5.2.1 and trying to make my web application available to all tenants. 
Following instructions from [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS521/Web+Applications) I've added ***carbon.enable.saas*** and ***carbon.saas.tenants*** parameters into web.xml however application can be accessed only by users of the domain where application is installed (i.e. if I deploy app under super tenant account then only users from global account have access ... and when I deploy app under tenant account only users from that tenant can login )

I'm seeing this error message on AS console:

*[2015-01-15 02:56:46,595]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.realms.CarbonTomcatRealm} -  Illegal access attempt by admin@tenant1.com to secured resource hosted by tenant carbon.super*

Looks like 5.2.1 for some reason ignores carbon.enable.saas. Any thoughts? Here is my web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
 <display-name>webApp</display-name>
 
 <context-param>
     <param-name>carbon.enable.saas</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>carbon.saas.tenants</param-name>
  <param-value>*</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Public access</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
   <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
 </security-constraint>

 <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Public access</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/docs/*</url-pattern>
   <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
 </security-constraint>

 <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Public access</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
   <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
 </security-constraint>



 <security-constraint>
  <display-name>Example Security Constraint</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>

   
   <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
   <http-method>GET</http-method>
   <http-method>POST</http-method>
   <http-method>PUT</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  
  
  <auth-constraint>
   <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
   <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  
  
 </security-constraint>
 <!-- Default login configuration uses form-based authentication -->
 <login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Example Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
   <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
   <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
 </login-config>


<!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
    <security-role>
        <role-name>everyone</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below context property alone, no need to put "carbon.saas.tenants" context property.

```
<context-param>
<param-name>carbon.enable.saas</param-name>
<param-value>*</param-value>
</context-param>
```